# Getting java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02291 for a nullable foreign key

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc

I am getting a `java.sql.SQLException`: ORA-02291 when I try to insert a `NULL` value to a column which has a foreign key constraint to another table. By definition this column is NULLABLE in the child table and the column it is referencing in the parent is the PK of that table.

I am confused, why I am getting this exception. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the exception and DDL

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; violated - parent key not found

            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:249)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
```

**DDL**

```
ALTER TABLE childtablename ADD CONSTRAINT constraintname FOREIGN KEY ( childtablecolumn )
REFERENCES parenttable(parenttablecolumn) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Code from my JUnit:

```
result = getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, new Object[]{
            notification.value1(),
            notification.value2(),
            notification.value3(), //this is for the column in contention, it is a int value and i have not initialized this variable 
            notification.value4(),
            notification.value5(),
            notification.value6(),
            notification.value7(),
            notification.value8(),
            notification.value9()
            });
```

Fact is I am able to insert a record to with a NULL value from SQL developer using a query directly. Its only failing when i am doing this programmatically.

Could Spring be the culprit here??

Comment: can you show the stack trace and the DDL of the table?

Comment: Exception

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; violated - parent key not found

            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:249)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)

   
DDL

ALTER TABLE childtablename ADD CONSTRAINT constraintname FOREIGN KEY ( childtablecolumn )
REFERENCES parenttable(parenttablecolumn) ON DELETE CASCADE;

Comment: Could you show the _code_ you use for inserting the data?

Comment: Please post your exception stacktrace as an edit to your original question and not in a comment. It's much too important to be buried in comments, and it also loses its formatting in comments and cannot be read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you haven't disclosed your data-access code, I can only guess that there is a problem in conveying the `NULL` value to the database. This is how to do it properly:

```
PreparedStatement ps = myConnection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO childtablename (pk_id, childtablecolumn) VALUES (?, ?)");

ps.setInt(1, id);
ps.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
```

You need to use the [`setNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29) method for the code to work.

Edit: Based on the unit test code snippet you provided, you could try this instead (setting the parameter to `null` explicitly):

```
result = getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, new Object[]{
        notification.value1(),
        notification.value2(),
        null, // <--
        notification.value4(),
        notification.value5(),
        notification.value6(),
        notification.value7(),
        notification.value8(),
        notification.value9()
        });
```

The reason for this is that if `notification.value3()` returns a primitive value (`int`) instead of an object (`Integer`), an unassigned value will be [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) into `Integer.valueOf(0)` instead of `null`, when the object array is created.

Comment: Thanks Mic. I am getting this exception when in my Junit for my DAO. And i am using spring jdbctemplate to create the entry.  Also i the column in contention is a NUMBER column and not VARCHAR. I probably think that's why it isn't working maybe.

Comment: Again, please add the relevant code (your test class) if you want a better answer.

Comment: This seems to be a likely cause -- you could also test it by temporarily disabling the foreign key to allow the insert, then inspect the row to see what value was actually inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the responses.

The suggestion by Mick worked, that is to set the value as null explicitly in the prepared statement, and since i was using spring jdbc template, in my case just pass the null value to the requisite parameter in the function as illustrated by the code snippet above

Pasting the fixes again

If you use Prepared Statement try the below:

```
PreparedStatement ps = myConnection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO childtablename (pk_id, childtablecolumn) VALUES (?, ?)");

ps.setInt(1, id);
ps.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
```

The fix that worked in my case (refer to the below trail for the answer from Mick):

```
result = getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, new Object[]{
            notification.value1(),
            notification.value2(),
            null, //this is for the column in contention, it is a primitive int value and i have not initialized this variable, so i had to do this to make it work
            notification.value4(),
            notification.value5(),
            notification.value6(),
            notification.value7(),
            notification.value8(),
            notification.value9()
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02291` indicates a constraint violation where a parent key is not found.

This means that the problem is not that you are trying to insert a `NULL` value in the child table , the problem is that the parent table does not contain a row with the value `NULL` for the referenced column.

PS : It may be that `foreign key` of child table is also `primary key` in the parent table(unless the parent has composite primary keys).So it won't allows `NULL` in the parent table.

EDIT 1: After additional info was inserted in the question by OP.

Whats happening here is `childtablecolumn` contains `NULL` values and parent table's `parenttablecolumn` does not contain a single row with the value of `NULL`.

Comment: It is perfectly okay to have a `null` value in a FK column (unless there is an additional `NOT NULL` constraint on the column).

Comment: @MickMnemonic: ya I know that. The problem  here is  that if the foreign key is referencing a single column in the parent table and the foreign key value is `NULL` then it will first try to find a row in the parent table with primary key value of  `NULL` and will throw an Exception

Comment: That does not make sense. Oracle does not allow `NULL` values in `PRIMARY KEY` columns.

Comment: @MickMnemonic: Ya that is what I said, the foreign key will have a NULL value in OP's case so it will try to find a reference to that in the parent table but it won't find a row with  NULL value there because as you mentioned we can't have ,and so the above exception will be thrown

Comment: Once more: [foreign keys can have `NULL` values](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_constraints.htm#i1006395) and primary keys (on the parent table) cannot; hence there would be no point in performing the check you suggest. `NULL` by definition is not a _value_ -- it means that the value is absent.

Comment: The parent could have a nullable unique key for the foreign key to reference, but this would not change the situation -- a null in a child table column cannot reference a null in a parent table column, because null does not equal null.